# How to connect points together using plot

Tags: matlab

I wrote some code that will searching for minimum of function using newton method. I've got some problem with plotting result. As a result I've got plot of not connected points but I want to get plot of connected points with the same colors. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
x = [[-1;-1],[-0.8;-0.8],[-0.6;-0.6],[-0.4;-0.4],[-0.2;-0.2],[0;0],[0.2;0.2],[0.4;0.4],[0.6;0.6],[0.8;0.8],[1;1]];
eps = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001];

f = @(x) x(1).^2 - 2.1*x(1).^4 + (x(1).^6)/3 + x(1)*x(2) - 4*x(2).^2 + 4*x(2).^4;

for i=1:length(x)
%    axis([0 0.001 0 100])
    colorVec = hsv(12);

    hold on;
    for e=1:length(eps)
        %fprintf('Starting point: %2.1f, %2.1f\n', x(:,i));
        %fprintf('Tollerance: %1.3f\n', eps(e));
        [r, iters] = NewtonMethod(f, x(:,i), eps(e), 100);
        plot(eps(e), iters, '-s', 'Color', colorVec(i,:))
    end
    hold off;

    xlabel('Tollerance')
    ylabel('Number of iterations')
    title('Title')
end
```

Pic related: [plot](http://bayimg.com/AAodoaaFF)

Comment: Currently, you are calling plot once for each point. Put together all points which belong to one line into a vector and plot them at once.

Comment: Which points do you want connected?  Same x and different eps?  Or same eps and different x?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it, following Daniel's comment:

```
x = [[-1;-1],[-0.8;-0.8],[-0.6;-0.6],[-0.4;-0.4],[-0.2;-0.2],[0;0],[0.2;0.2],[0.4;0.4],    [0.6;0.6],[0.8;0.8],[1;1]];
eps = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001];

f = @(x) x(1).^2 - 2.1*x(1).^4 + (x(1).^6)/3 + x(1)*x(2) - 4*x(2).^2 + 4*x(2).^4;

iters = zeros(length(x),length(eps));
for i=1:length(x)
    colorVec = hsv(12);

    hold on;
    for e=1:length(eps)
        %fprintf('Starting point: %2.1f, %2.1f\n', x(:,i));
        %fprintf('Tolerance: %1.3f\n', eps(e));
        [r, iters(i,e)] = NewtonMethod(f, x(:,i), eps(e), 100);
    end
    hold off;

    xlabel('Tolerance')
    ylabel('Number of iterations')
    title('Title')
end
% choose one of these:
plot(iters);
plot(iters');
```